# Linq to SQL access "raw" FK column

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am having an interesting issue dealing with a Navigation Property, which is defined in the DB as a foreign key WITH NOCHECK.

Basically, the relationship is between a user record and a document that the user produces as a work product, related by the username (i.e. doc.UserName = user.UserName).  The FK constraint is not checked on deletion, the idea being that if the user leaves the organization, the document should remain behind and the now-deleted username still stored as author.

At a database level, this is working great; however, because the relationship is defined via a Navigation Property, I would like to display the username and cannot because the user record is Nothing / null.

My question is, is there a way to access and / or expose the "raw" table column in my LINQ model so that I can directly access it in the code when the user record no longer exists?  (FYI, I am using .NET 3.5)

Comment: While it doesn't solve the general issue, in this particular case you could always soft delete the user entity. That way you're keeping referential integrity, and what if the user comes back or someone told you to delete the wrong user.

Comment: Agreed, and that would tend to be my usual approach vs. a hard delete.  However, this is a legacy app with long established behavior in this regard.

Another workaround of course would be a manual SQL query for the column if the user record is null, but clearly that would not be very elegant at all.  I was really hoping there was some way to pull back the covers (so to speak) using LINQ.